# finding the rightmost different bit

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

```
package Bitwise;

public class rightmostDifferentBit 
{
  static void findBit(int n, int m) {
    int res= 1;
    for(int i=0;i<math.max(m,n);i++) {
        res = res <<i;
        int temp1 = m & res;
        int temp2 = n & res;
        if(temp1!=temp2) {
           System.out.println(i+1);
           break;
        }
     }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findBit(52,4);

    }
}
```

In this code I don't know why loop runs only up to `i=3`. Why not run until `res <= max(m,n)`. Can anyone explain what can be the error?

Comment: `res = 1 << i;` otherwise you have shifted by 6 bits after steps 0, 1, 2, and 3 if you continue to shift the already shifted `res`.

Comment: You should be looking for the least significant bit in `n ^ m`. You can find this with `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeroes`.

Comment: @luk2302 can you please elaborate why i have to shift 6 bits ? ..it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: You must not shift by 6, but you do shift by 6, after i=3 you shifted 0, then 1, then 2, then 3 and 0+1+2+3=6 since you shift the already shifted res over and over again. After i=4 you have shifted by 10 bits, then 15, then 21.